# How to set a width of a class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to set a width of my class by finding the container width and remove 110px.

This is what I have, where initialW is a var

```
$(".col-80").width = initialW - 110;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.css( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) function to set the css for selected elements.

```
$(".col-80").css("width", (initialW - 110) + "px");
```

**Edit**

The method you are trying could get you the desired result with little tune up, by converting the jQuery object to DOM and accessing `width` property through `style`.

```
$(".col-80")[0].style.width = (initialW - 110) + "px";
```

As pointed by @Matej Žvan you can use [.width( value )](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2)

```
$(".col-80").width((initialW - 110) + "px");
```

Comment: why use .css() if you have .width() function?

Comment: Thanks @MatejŽvan, that is even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var initialW = $(".col-80").width();
$(".col-80").width( initialW - 110 )
```

.width() can return width in int value (widouth px) or set it to a value if you pas a value to it